# Multi-kafka connections

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

There is a data stream application. It is necessary to connect and listen from several Kafka brokers (different ip-addresses, more than 2) and to write to the one.

Pls advise how to arrange multi-kafka connection?

Configuration class for a single kafka connection:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducer {


    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:29092");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

It is expected several connections to be arranged and listened in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap server config option accepts a CSV list for multiple brokers of one cluster. But you only need to provide multiple options for fault tolerance, as Kafka automatically returns all servers in the same cluster on first connection.

If you need to connect to distinct Kafka clusters, create a Bean with the different bootstrap address